# Forcing someone for namaz

Tags: salat

Salam alaikum brothers, lately I have been praying 5 times a day in masjid Alhamdolillah but at the same time I hav been urging/forcing my colleagues for prayer as well sometimes making them feel bad about not praying and I also feel that I am doing a bad thing. I feel I should stop doing this and let them be. Is it right?

Comment: The title of your question is about **forcing** people to pray, but the body is about advising them verbally. Please clarify if your question is about forcing or advising.

Comment: Verbally embarrassing them

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should refrain from indulging in the personal lives of other people. The acceptance and following of religion is a personal matter between an individual and the creator. You as a commoner have no right to force, oppress, intimidate or install the law of Islam, unless you become a rightful caliph, even then your authority would be limited.

You may simply ask them nicely and give an invitation to follow Islam. Accepting or refusing is their choice. As the Quran states:

> There shall be no compulsion in the religion. The right course has
> become clear from the wrong. So whoever disbelieves in evil and
> believes in Allah has grasped the most trustworthy handhold with no
> break in it. And Allah is Hearing and Knowing.
>
> Quran 2:256

Therefore, you should stop making them bad about not praying, because nothing good is ever going to come out from that. Soon they will start despising you and they may also start to despise Islam. This will result in more harm than good.

Comment: This ignores source texts like "command the good and forbid the evil", "religion is good advice" etc., and rulings derived from those texts.

Comment: Sorry, I can't agree with you because there is no incident where the prophet pbuh enforced on or insulted his colleagues/companions for not praying? He simply asked them and they accepted. The ones who did not accept like Abu Talib, the prophet prayed for them but he didn't embarrassed him. Forbidding evil does not mean to make yourself miserable where everyone will start to hate you. This sort of behaviour may lead to violence & terrorism. We may forbid evil just like the Prophet did. He didn't enforced anything unless he became a King. The person who has asked the question is not a caliph.

Comment: JaZaK AllaH Khair Brothers

Comment: It feels your answer is directed against non Muslim forcing while the question is directed on Muslims..

Comment: @Kilise A non muslim is not obligated to pray 5 times a day. So it does not make sense to either force them or ask them nicely to go perform the pray. My answer specifically refers towards directing Muslims